# Remote desktop windows 7 windows 2008

Tags: remote-desktop

I'm trying to connect to Windows 2008 via Remote Desktop on Windows 7. 
I get the error message saying: "this computer can't connect to remote computer".

The port is allowed in the firewall, remote service is up... 
I can connect with telnet to the machine on port 3389.
Server is not local, it's on the internet, other people can connect to it.

Any idea what can cause this?

Comment: 3389 is not the ip but a port. Can you ping the server from the Win7?

Comment: <ip> 3389 .. better?
everything works .. nothing uses 3389 ...